# shorthand for custom components in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've recently learnt that you can make a custom component like this:

```
const CustomComp=()=>{
 console.log('Created custom comp');
 return(<View></View>);
}

export default function App(){
 return(<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <CustomComp />
 </View>)
}
```

but is it possible to do it in shorthand maybe something like this?

```
export default function App(){
 return(<View style={{flex:1}}>
  <(()=>{
     console.log('Created custom comp');
     return(<View></View>);
    }) />
 </View>)
}
```

it's not accurate but I guess you get the general idea of my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just evaluate a function in place using an IIFE:

```
export default function App(){
 return(<View style={{flex:1}}>
  {(() => {
     console.log('Created custom comp');
     return(<View></View>);
  })()}
 </View>)
}
```

Comment: works like a charm, also one more question how do I add `React.memo` in it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with React Native, so not sure what `React.memo` is. Please note that the inline function is *not* a component, so you cannot treat is as one (e.g., hooks will not work, etc). I think it's simpler to just extract it as a proper component if you need such features.

Comment: `React.memo` is a react.js feature , see if you could incorporate it within your solution
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-alRbk_zP0

Comment: Ah ok, `useMemo()`. Well, I'm not 100% sure how it would behave, but you can create an ad-hoc component within the inlined function and use it immediately. I don't think it's worth your trouble, though.